# Is it possible to allow a participant to select multiple options in the choice field?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to ask the participants about what languages they speak.  Needless to say, they may need to choose several options.  I thought about letting them fill in a box but since there will be many many participants it may be difficult to get accurate search results when we are evaluating the data later on.

Is it possible to allow them to select several options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Checkboxes type in the Choice field will allow your users to select multiple options.